# Using 'div' class name or title inside JSTL conditional tag

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, jstl

I have a `<div>` tag, I pass the `<div>` tag to a JavaScript call, based on the result on that JavaScript I set the title and class of the tag.

Once I returned from JavaScript, in the JSP page I want to use the modified `<div>` title or class in JSTL tags (JSTL code is inside `<div>` block) to enable or disable few lines in that block.

Is there anyway I can access `<div>` title or class inside JSTL condition tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. The JSP is executed server-side, in response to a browser request and the JavaScript is executed on the client-side, after the page contents have been sent to the browser.

To send something back from the client to the server, you could use HTML form post or an AJAX call to put/post the modified class and title data back to the server.

A good place to start for writing AJAX calls in JavaScript is on the [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest), or if you prefer incurring a small overhead, the jQuery library has [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) support.